# I need to extract data from a text file that contains >8 million records. What is the best suited language to do this using Multithreading?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, dataframe, multiprocessing

Currently I am using Multiprocessing feature of Python. Though this works fine for text file up to 2 million records, it fails for the file with 8 million records with "Can't access lock."

Moreover, it takes about 30 minutes to process the file with 2 million records and fails like after about an hour or so for the big file.

I am doing this:

```
def try_multiple_operations(item):
        aab_type = item[15:17]
        aab_amount = item[35:46]
        aab_name = item[82:100]
        aab_reference = item[64:82]
        if aab_type not in '99' or 'Z5':
            aab_record = f'{aab_name} {aab_amount} {aab_reference}'
        else: 
            aab_record = 'ignore'
        return aab_record
```

Calling the try_multiple_operations in the `__main__`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   //some other code

    executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(10)
    futures = [executor.submit(try_multiple_operations, item) for item in aab ]
    concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
    aab_list = [x.result() for x in futures]
    aab_list.sort()

    //some other code for further processing
```

I have used pandas/dataframes too. I am able to do a bit of the processing using that. However, I want to be able to retain the original format of the file after processing which dataframes make a bit tricky as they return data in either ndarray format or acsv format.

I would like to understand if there is a faster way of doing this, maybe using some other programming language.

Comment: i think it's better to optimize it in a language you know well. Java is known for its powerful concurrency model. But it may not be easy to learn a new language and it's internals(multi-threading model) just for this one case.

Comment: `... for item in aab ]` - what is `aab`? Can you give an example of an `item`?

Comment: `aab` is an array of records from a text file. It is a fixed length file from which I am extracting subsets for usage later.

Comment: I can iterate over a 100K line file, extract all those slices; construct a string and append to a list for each of those lines in about 0.24 seconds without any concurrency - that should be about 19.2 seconds for an 8e6 line file. Why are you using multiprocessing?

Comment: Doing the same for a one million line file took about 2.44 seconds so it seems pretty linear.

Comment: `I would like to understand if there is a faster way of doing this..` How can we know if we do not have a minimal example of the data (`aab`)? Pleas read [mre].

Comment: @wwii Thanks. I have simplified the code to get rid of the multiprocessing bit. Apparently it was taking more time with multiprocessing than without it.

Comment: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

As advised by @wwii, updated the code to get rid of the multiprocessing. This made the code a lot faster.

```
def try_multiple_operations(items):
    data_aab = []
    value = ['Z5','RA','Z4','99', 99]
    for item in items:
        aab_type = item[15:17]
        aab_amount = item[35:46]
        aab_name = item[82:100]
        aab_reference = item[64:82]
        if aab_type not in value:
            # aab_record = f'{aab_name} {aab_amount} {aab_reference}'
            data_aab.append(f'{aab_name} {aab_amount} {aab_reference}')
    return data_aab
```

Called this as:

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     #some code
     aab_list = try_multiple_operations(aab)
     #some extra code
```

This, while a bit surprising for me, is a lot faster than multiprocessing.